# Including privacy manifest in package.swift with binary target

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, privacy-manifest

I'm working on a 3rd party SDK (XCFramework) which is distributed a binary target via Swift Package Manager. Following last WWDC we need to include the privacy manifest as part of the package.

While there's a quick solution for ["regular"](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#target) targets by adding the file path to `resources: [.process("Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy")]`, I couldn't find any example or straightforward solution for adding the `.xcprivacy` file for a binary target which currently offer this options:

```
static func binaryTarget(
    name: String,
    path: String
) -> Target
```

```
static func binaryTarget(
    name: String,
    url: String,
    checksum: String
) -> Target
```

Has anyone found a solution for it yet?

Comment: So your package *only* has one target, and that target is a binary target?

Comment: Yes. One binary target

Answer (score 1):

One way is to include the manifest in a wrapper target, like this [grpc example](https://github.com/google/grpc-binary/blob/main/Package.swift#L50C1-L65C7):

```
    .target(
      name: "grpcppWrapper",
      dependencies: [
        "grpcpp",
      ],
      path: "grpcpp-Wrapper",
      resources: [.process("Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy")]
    ),
    .binaryTarget(
      name: "grpcpp",
      url: "https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.62.1/rc1/grpcpp.zip",
      checksum: "8075379cb5ab3fb84afca729e215b2503f20648e17d960a9fe013812156a42e0"
    ),
```